# In Shiny, what's the difference between req() and an if() statement?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

Let's say I have the following UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
checkboxGroupInput("checkbox", "", choices = colnames(mtcars)),
tableOutput("table")
)
```

I want to render a table of `mtcars` once at least one checkbox option has been selected. For this, I came across `req()`, but I can't see how is it different from an `if` statement, even reading the documentation about this function, it's definition is very close to what an `if` statement does:

> Ensure that values are available ("truthy"–see Details) before
>   proceeding with a calculation or action. If any of the given values is
>   not truthy, the operation is stopped by raising a "silent" exception
>   (not logged by Shiny, nor displayed in the Shiny app's UI).

So, how is this table rendering:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderTable({
    req(input$checkbox)
    mtcars %>% select(input$checkbox)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

different from this one?:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderTable({
    if(!is.null(input$checkbox))
    mtcars %>% select(input$checkbox)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

TL;DR: how is `req()` different from an `if` statement other than how you write it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you can see the code for `req` by typing its name without the parenthesis.

```
function (..., cancelOutput = FALSE) 
{
    dotloop(function(item) {
        if (!isTruthy(item)) {
            if (isTRUE(cancelOutput)) {
                cancelOutput()
            }
            else {
                reactiveStop(class = "validation")
            }
        }
    }, ...)
    if (!missing(..1)) 
        ..1
    else invisible()
}
```

What's basically happening is that it loops over all the values you pass in and checks if they look "truthy" rather than just checking for null. And if so, it will cancel the output. And `if` statement will only conditionally execute a block of code, it will not cancel the output necessarily. When you have this block for example

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderTable({
      if(!is.null(input$checkbox)) 
         mtcars %>% select(input$checkbox)
      print("ran")
    })
}
```

The code inside the `if` expression is conditioanally run, but The `print()` after is still always run because it's not in the `if` block. But with a `req`

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderTable({
      req(input$checkbox)
      mtcars %>% select(input$checkbox)
      print("ran")
    })
}
```

The `req()` basically aborts the rest of the block so the `print()` doesn't run if the `req` is not a "truthy" value. It just makes it easier to prevent unnecessary code from running.